# wcf service accessing two or more db on same server

Tags: web-services, wcf, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have 2 DB on same server named as

1. Test1
2. ReportServer

I do have a set of wcf services with web.config file having connection-string to 'Test1' which works fine, and  my other db 'ReportServer' use to publish SSRS report links derived from data located in 'Test1'.

Any Idea how do I design a wcf-service to get the published links

Comment: Why can't you just have two connection strings in your web.config?

Comment: And how would I differentiate to access which server at the service level ? Any example or reference ?

Comment: Let me get this straight. Do you have 2 different WCF services (where each will access a separate database) or 1 WCF service that will access 2 different databases?

Comment: The first clause..2 different WCF services that will access 2 different databases

Comment: other-wise how do I design a web-service to address 'ReportServer' within same solution.

Comment: You could build 1 WCF service, where one Method connects to Test1 db, and another connects to ReportServer. But ok - in your web.config you would add a connectionString. In 1 service it would point to Test1, and in the other it would point to ReportServer. You will want to make sure that the login you use in the ReportServer connectionString also has access to the Test1 db.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit it and describe exactly what you require. For example, what do you mean by *I do have a set of wcf services* and *links derived from data located in 'Test1'*?

Comment: I just want to display a list of published ssrs reports link which is based on 'ReportServer' Db on Web pages which get served by WCF Services based on 'Test1' db, both dbs are on same server.